# Classic tentacled alien movie where its blood spawns new aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a classic tentacled alien movie. I watched this when I was really young so I can't really recall the title anymore.

1. The setting happened in outer space inside a space vehicle.
2. The aliens have a slimy dark colored skin. One very big eye in its head, they sway their tentacles constantly when they move around.
3. There is a scene where they shoot the aliens and thought it's already dead... but new aliens spawn from the blood left in the ship.
4. They can hide from the aliens when they point a light (flash light or spot light) on its eye.
5. There is a scene when a ship was overrun by these aliens because they kept on shooting them but new aliens sprung from blood all around.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: When were you "really young"?

Comment: There are some people online who were "really young" in the early 2000s, and others who were "really young" in the 1950s.  Knowing when you watched the movie (in absolute terms, rather than relative terms like "really young") would greatly help us in identifying likely candidates.

Comment: These aliens sound like Kang and Kodos.

Answer (score 8):

The 1968 film *[The Green Slime](https://hqofk.wordpress.com/2016/10/26/the-green-slime-1968/)* fits what you're looking for (my bolding).

[image: Movie poster]

> There’s a tense romantic and professional rivalry between Horton and his astronaut colleague Richard Jaeckel, and best of all there’s an onslaught of rapidly-multiplying alien monsters. The critters sneak on board the Gamma III **space station** after its astronauts return from blowing up a giant killer asteroid (a cool mission in itself). The men bring back a bit of sticky, foamy matter that looks like lime green jello, just enough to fill a thimble, but more than enough to spawn an army of aliens that will spell doom for the station, and possibly Earth as well. This tiny green blob feeds off energy sources, expanding with lightning speed to its final form, a **one-eyed monster with a hide like prickly fruit. It waddles and squeaks, and flails its electrocuting tentacles about maniacally** like the giant inflatable tube at your local car dealership. The crew shoots the things with lasers, isolates them with the airlock system, turns off the power and light (that works for a bit), but **wounded aliens bleed, every drop of mucus spawns another horde**, and soon there are oodles of them crawling along the outside of the station like barnacles. Game over for the Gamma, as crew decides to evacuate and nuke the joint on their way out.

### Trailer

Found on page 2 of search terms of *film space alien tentacles blood spawns new aliens*.

Comment: If this does turn out to be the answer, don't forget to upvote and to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept.

Comment: BTW, the movie inspired the classic 1980 board game Awful Green Things From Outer Space: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TabletopGame/TheAwfulGreenThingsFromOuterSpace "In the instructions, the game's creator Wham credits the Japanese/American film The Green Slime as a major influence."

Comment: @jeffronicus: ^_^ Neat. I remember hearing about that game in Dragon magazine and I had a moment of "Hey, that sounds like..." when I was posting the answer.