Science Fiction boardgame.Two players (maybe more possible) Torus shaped spaceship gameboard You control reproducing aliens. Played 1986-1988
I used to play this game at the house of a friend while I was studying for my A levels. We always played it as a two player game. I don't know if more players were allowed. A full game took maybe 25-40 minutes. The rectangular gameboard was relatively small. Maybe half the size of a Monopoly board.
I am trying to find out the name of the game.
I have a clear memory of him teaching me to play. He explained that one side of the gameboard linked to the other side as it represented a torus shaped spaceship.
I think at least one player played as aliens which could bud to reproduce and wanted to take over the ship. Possibily the other person played humans, I do not remember clearly.The cardboard alien counters showed blobs (possibly green.) I think I remember first aid kit counters.

Did the sides fight, or was it a race to occupy strategic points?  What did the non (green?) alien counters look like?  Were there weapons?  Did certain spots on the map have bonuses/resources/power-ups?  Did you have to open and close doors/bulkheads, or was the map fixed?

I do not recall fighting. Maybe the other side's counters had little astronauts. This is a vague, possibly wrong memory. I can remember first aid kits.

The shape of the map was always the same I think but you could discover different things in different compartments on each playthrough.

I think I do recall opening bulkheads, but not why this was necessary.

Though it got already a correct answer, it might be a better fit on https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/

Thank you @Zibelas I did not know there was a boardgames SE.

I don't have a copy to check, but this sounds like it might be the 1979 game The Awful Green Things from Outer Space.
I don't have a photo of the TSR version that you likely played, but here's the 1989 Steve Jackson Games version:

Yes this is it. I found a photo of the gameboard I remember.

It certainly matches a ship-based board game where a human crew fights off a green alien foe that grows by splitting and laying eggs.
The SF Encyclopedia has a bit more about the game mechanics:

The crew of the alien spacecraft Znutar have suffered "an unexpected encounter of the worst kind"; a mineral sample picked up from an unexplored planet turns out to be an egg of an implacably hostile species, the eponymous Things. While the Znutar's personnel have access to a range of weapons, from cans of rocket fuel to unused containers of edible Zgwortz, their effect is unknown until they have been tried, being randomly determined once for each session of the game. Weapons may hurt or stun the Things, cause them to grow or blow them into fragments, each of which becomes a new Thing.


^_^ Jinx! I remembered it in part because I remember reading a review years ago and in part because I provided the movie it was based on as an answer some years ago at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153580/classic-tentacled-alien-movie-where-its-blood-spawns-new-aliens/153587#153587

I bet this game could be adapted into a tabletop Among Us.

Could it be The Awful Green Things From Space?


The Awful Green Things From Outer Space is a board game originally created for TSR of Dungeons & Dragons fame by Tom Wham, and first published in 1980. After being out of print for many years, the rights for the game were picked up by Steve Jackson Games. The game is again out of print, but there's still an official webpage on the SJG website with some details and extra goodies, and copies of the many and varied editions are available on eBay.
The game is for two players, one of whom controls the eponymous Things, while the other controls the non-human multiracial crew of the starship Znutar, the rooms and corridors of which make up the board. The AGT are seeded on board and attempt to multiply and devour the crew, while the crew must collect and test various would-be weapons, applying a randomly-drawn chit to determine the effects, hoping to wipe out the Things. The game tends to heavily favor the Things, which can reproduce and replace their losses, while the crew are pretty much doomed if they fight hand-to-hand, and must desperately try to scrounge up a weapon that kills the Things, instead of being useless or even causing the creatures to grow.

Potentially not matching, the ship map does not seem to loop on its own, but the rules note that you can exit the ship into space, and then move along the outside in a fairly circular fashion.


"Potentially not matching, the ship map does not seem to loop on its own, but the rules note that you can exit the ship into space, and then move along the outside in a fairly circular fashion" Indeed. You have the correct game and I had misremembered that aspect.
